# gcc workaround while using shared_ptr to insert in std::set

Tags: c++, g++

This code fails to compile using g++ 4.2.1 but works fine under vc++ v8.

```
#include <set>
typedef std::set<int *> IntPtrSet;
IntPtrSet iptrSet;

typedef std::set<shared_ptr<int>> IntPtrSet2;
IntPtrSet2 iptrSet2;

void AddIntegers(int& x)
{
    iptrSet.insert(&x);
    iptrSet2.insert(&x);
}
```

shared_ptr is similar to boost::shared_ptr or tr1::shared_ptr.

It emits the following errors,

```
No matching function for call to std::allocator<shared_ptr<int>>::construct(int**, const shared_ptr<int>&)
No matching function for call to std::allocator<shared_ptr<int> >::destroy(int **)
```

Did anyone encounter such error before? If yes, what is the workaround.

Here is the complete error message:

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h:402: error: no matching function for call to 'std::allocator<shared_ptr<int> >::destroy(int**)'

/Users/mark/Templates/Function/main.cpp:188:   instantiated from here
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h:380: error: no matching function for call to 'std::allocator<shared_ptr<int> >::construct(int**, const shared_ptr<int>&)'
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/new_allocator.h:106: note: candidates are: void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Tp*, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = shared_ptr<int>]
```

Complete Template Instantiation stack:

```
/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x c++ -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot 
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mfix-and-continue -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -iquote   /Users/mark/Templates/Function/build/Function.build/Debug/Function.build/Function-generated-files.hmap - I/Users/mark/Templates/Function/build/Function.build/Debug/Function.build/Function-own-target-headers.hmap - I/Users/mark/Templates/Function/build/Function.build/Debug/Function.build/Function-all- target-headers.hmap -iquote  /Users/mark/Templates/Function/build/Function.build/Debug/Function.build/Function-project- headers.hmap -F/Users/mark/Templates/Function/build/Debug - I/Users/mark/Templates/Function/build/Debug/include - I/Users/mark/Templates/Function/build/Function.build/Debug/Function.build/DerivedSources/x86 _64 - I/Users/mark/Templates/Function/build/Function.build/Debug/Function.build/DerivedSources -c  /Users/mark/Templates/Function/main.cpp -o  /Users/mark/Templates/Function/build/Function.build/Debug/Function.build/Objects- normal/x86_64/main.o

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h: In member function 'void std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_destroy_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>*) [with _Key = shared_ptr<int>, _Val = shared_ptr<int>, _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<shared_ptr<int> >, _Compare = std::less<shared_ptr<int> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<shared_ptr<int> >]':

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h:1327:   instantiated from 'void std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>*) [with _Key = shared_ptr<int>, _Val = shared_ptr<int>, _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<shared_ptr<int> >, _Compare = std::less<shared_ptr<int> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<shared_ptr<int> >]'

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h:594:   instantiated from 'std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::~_Rb_tree() [with _Key = shared_ptr<int>, _Val = shared_ptr<int>, _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<shared_ptr<int> >, _Compare = std::less<shared_ptr<int> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<shared_ptr<int> >]'

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_set.h:141:   instantiated from 'std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::set() [with _Key = shared_ptr<int>, _Compare = std::less<shared_ptr<int> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<shared_ptr<int> >]'
```

/Users/mark/Templates/Function/main.cpp:181:   instantiated from here

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h:402: error: no matching function for call to 'std::allocator<shared_ptr<int> >::destroy(int**)'

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/new_allocator.h:110: note: candidates are: void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::destroy(_Tp*) [with _Tp = shared_ptr<int>]

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h: In member function 'std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_create_node(const _Val&) [with _Key = shared_ptr<int>, _Val = shared_ptr<int>, _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<shared_ptr<int> >, _Compare = std::less<shared_ptr<int> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<shared_ptr<int> >]':

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h:840:   instantiated from 'typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, const _Val&) [with _Key = shared_ptr<int>, _Val = shared_ptr<int>, _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<shared_ptr<int> >, _Compare = std::less<shared_ptr<int> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<shared_ptr<int> >]'

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h:988:   instantiated from 'std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator, bool> std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique(const _Val&) [with _Key = shared_ptr<int>, _Val = shared_ptr<int>, _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<shared_ptr<int> >, _Compare = std::less<shared_ptr<int> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<shared_ptr<int> >]'

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_set.h:307:   instantiated from 'std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Key, std::_Identity<_Key>, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator, bool> std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const _Key&) [with _Key = shared_ptr<int>, _Compare = std::less<shared_ptr<int> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<shared_ptr<int> >]'

/Users/mark/Templates/Function/main.cpp:188:   instantiated from here

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h:380: error: no matching function for call to 'std::allocator<shared_ptr<int> >::construct(int**, const shared_ptr<int>&)'

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/new_allocator.h:106: note: candidates are: void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Tp*, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = shared_ptr<int>]
```

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
template <class T>
class shared_ptr
{
    private:
    T* m_p;
public:
shared_ptr() throw() : m_p(NULL){}

shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<T>& p) throw()
{
      m_p = p;
}

shared_ptr( T* p) throw()
{
    m_p = p;
}

~shared_ptr() throw()
{
    m_p = NULL;
}

T* operator=(const shared_ptr<T>& p) throw()
{
    if (m_p != p.m_p)
    {
        m_p = p;
    }
    return m_p;
}

T* operator=(T* p) throw()
{
    if (m_p != p)
    {
        m_p = p;
    }
    return m_p;
}

operator T*() const throw()
{
    return m_p;
}

T& operator*() const throw()
{
    return *m_p;
}

T** operator&() throw()
{
    return &m_p;
}

bool operator!() const throw()
{
    return (m_p == NULL);
}

bool operator<(T* p) const throw()
{
    return m_p < p;
}

bool operator!=(int nNull) const throw()
{
    return !operator==(nNull);
}

bool operator==( int nNull) const throw()
{
    return m_p == NULL;
}

bool operator!=( T* p) const throw()
{
    return !operator==(p);
}

bool operator==( T* p) const throw()
{
    return m_p == p;
}

void CopyTo( T** pp) const throw()
{
    *pp = m_p;
}

void Release() throw()
{
    T* p = m_p;
    if (p)
    {
        m_p = NULL;
    }
}

void Attach( T* p) throw()
{
    m_p = p;
}

T* Detach() throw()
{
    T* p = m_p;
    m_p = NULL;
    return p;
}
```

};

```
#include <set>
typedef std::set<int *> IntPtrSet;
IntPtrSet iptrSet;

typedef std::set<shared_ptr<int> > IntPtrSet2;
IntPtrSet2 iptrSet2;

void AddIntegers(int& x)
{
iptrSet.insert(&x);

shared_ptr<int> intPtr(new int(3));

iptrSet2.insert(intPtr);
}


int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {


char c;
std::cin >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

Also on the Dinkumware site the code compiled successfully. It fails to compile using g++ as mentioned earlier.FYI, I have pasted the result from the Dinkumware website (http://www.dinkumware.com/exam/default.aspx) below.

Your code has been compiled with the Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 C++ compiler using
the Dinkum C++ library from the Dinkum Compleat Libraries for VC++ package.

This is the compiler output using the code above in a file named
sourceFile.cpp:

---

sourceFile.cpp

---

size sourceFile.exe :
6144t + 3584 .rdata + 512d = 10240 (2800)

Code compiled successfully!
The executable generated was 11 KB.

Thanks a lot

Regards,
Mark

Comment: It would be nice if you provided full error message, including template instantiation stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `shared_ptr` implementation seems very unusual.

Compared to boost/tr1, you have extra converting operators for T** and T*. Implicitly converting to the underlying pointer type (T*) is only going to confuse the compiler.

After I commented out those methods, I had to fix the copy constructor to actually copy member-wise rather than abusing the converting operator. It still won't work as a shared pointer because there's no reference counting.

Then I had to fix `operator<` to take `const shared_ptr<T>& p` again because the implicit conversions were causing this to compile, but confusing the compiler on the `std::set` later on. It got confused because it was trying to construct a `shared_ptr` but the `operator&` (I think) caused it to degrade to `T**` so the type didn't match the type inside the container.

With those changes I was able to get it to successfully compile with g++ 4.2.

EDIT:
Well, I was able to write a custom allocator that compiles but it doesn't seem terribly clean and may not even work in all cases.

```
template <class T>
class sh_ptr_alloc : public std::allocator<T>
{
public:
        typedef size_t     size_type;

      sh_ptr_alloc() throw() { }

      template<typename Tp1>
        sh_ptr_alloc(const sh_ptr_alloc<Tp1>&) throw() { }

      template<typename Tp1>
        struct rebind
        { typedef sh_ptr_alloc<Tp1> other; };

template <class Tp1>
      void
      deallocate(Tp1* p, size_type)
      { ::operator delete(p); }

template <class Tp1>
      void 
      construct(Tp1** p, const shared_ptr<Tp1>& val) 
      { ::new(p) shared_ptr<int>(val); }

template <class Tp1>
      void 
      destroy(Tp1** p) { }
};
```

The set is then:

`typedef std::set<shared_ptr<int>, std::less<shared_ptr<int> >, sh_ptr_alloc<shared_ptr<int> > > IntPtrSet2;`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. :) The problem is the shared_ptr that I am using is part of the code which I don't have permission to change. A lot of other client code depends on the implicit converting operators. Is there any other workaround without changing shared_ptr?

Comment: @Mark Understood. But also consider: If a lot of code depends on the implicit conversions, think how much code could be broken unknowingly because the implicit conversions are invoked in unexpected ways?

Comment: Agreed. I'll push for using a better shared_ptr. Thanks for your solution using custom allocator. :)

Answer (score 6):

For (obvious) reason, there is not implicit conversion from `T*` to `shared_ptr<T>`.

For example, the following code fails:

```
int i = 3;
shared_ptr<int> ptr;
ptr = &i;
```

There is a good reason for that: the `shared_ptr` OWNS the resources it points to. You cannot blindly throw something into a `shared_ptr` to get free memory management, you have to make sure that the object is not already owned by something else.

The solution is to use either the constructor or a builder:

```
shared_ptr<int> ptr(new int(3));

shared_ptr<int> ptr = shared_ptr<int>(new int(3));

shared_ptr<int> made = make_shared<int>(3);
```

The last method leads to a slightly more compact pointer, though the difference is unlikely to affect you.

I would stress that your example is fishy. Ownership is better enforced right at creation time. In a function like such, chances are someone else has acquired the ownership already and that you're creating a Big Bad Bug.

Comment: I tried these, but i still get the same error message. I have posted the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's having trouble with the conversion from int* to shared_ptr.  I think the workaround is fairly simple:

```
shared_ptr<int> intPtr(&x);
iptrSet2.insert(intPtr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void AddIntegers(int& x)
{
...
    iptrSet2.insert(&x);
```

This probably fails, because there is no implicit conversion form `int*` to `boost::shared_ptr<int>`. You'll have to construct it manually (and beware: for one object, only one shared_ptr can be constructed; other pointers must be creaied as copies of this one "master" shared pointer).

Comment: I have tried that, but it still fails. Posted the complete error message and stack. thanks