# How to use QSet as value in QMap?

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qmap, qset

I'm using Qt and I want to declare following container:

```
QMap<QUrl , QSet<ClassSharedPtr> > map;
```

Here ClassSharedPtr is the boost shared ptr of class "Class".

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<const Class> ClassPtr;
```

I'm getting following errors after adding header file #include :

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘qHash(const boost::shared_ptr<const Class>&)’
```

Comment: Normally that means you are missing a header inclusion.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Did you see that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997340/gcc-workaround-while-using-shared-ptr-to-insert-in-stdset

Answer (score 0):

`QSet`'s value data type must be an assignable data type. In addition, the type must provide `operator==()`, and there must also be a `qHash()` function in the type's namespace that returns a hash value for an argument of the values's type.

So, you should implement `qHash()` function for `boost::shared_ptr<const Class>`.

```
namespace boost {

uint qHash(const boost::shared_ptr<const Class> &key, uint seed = 0)
{
    const Class *ptr = key.get();
    return uint(ptr) ^ seed;
}

}
```